# OpenCSV memberFieldsToBindTo not working - Java

Tags: java, opencsv

I am trying to use OpenCSV to parse a CSV file into a list of objects so I can load student data into my Student Team Allocator system.

I have been following this [guide](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/#read-a-csv-file-and-parse-the-records-into-a-java-object) under the heading *'Parsing the records into a Java Object'*

After some issues with dependencies I have it outputting a list of Student objects, however the CSV columns are not bound to the member fields as they should be. Print test returns null values for every object's fields.

I have two constructors in Student, one that initialises the 3 fields, and one that is empty. I know currently the empty one gets used as removing this one causes InstantiationExceptions in the Student object.

CSVParser Class

```
public class CSVParser {

private static String CSV_FILE_PATH;

public CSVParser(String CSVPath){
    CSV_FILE_PATH = CSVPath; 

    try (
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(CSV_FILE_PATH));
    ) {
        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
        strategy.setType(Student.class);
        String[] memberFieldsToBindTo = {"fName", "sName", "stuNumber"};
        strategy.setColumnMapping(memberFieldsToBindTo);

        CsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
                .withSkipLines(1)
                .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                .build();

        List<Student> Students = csvToBean.parse();

        for (Student s : Students) {
            System.out.println("First Name : " + s.getFirstName());
            System.out.println("Second Name : " + s.getSecondName());
            System.out.println("StudentNo : " + s.getStudentNumber());
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CSVParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

  }
}
```

Student Class

```
public class Student {

private String fName;
private String sName;
private String stuNumber;
private String skill;
private final String[] skills = {"Planning","Writing","Developing"};

public Student(){

}

public Student(String fName, String sName, String stuNumber) {
    this.fName = fName;
    this.sName = sName;
    this.stuNumber = stuNumber;
}

// Setters
public void setSkill(int skillIndex){
    this.skill = skills[skillIndex];
}

public void setFirstName(String fName){
    this.fName = fName;
}

public void setSecondName(String sName){
    this.sName = sName;
}

public void setStudentNumber(String stuNumber){
    this.stuNumber = stuNumber;
}

// Getters
public String getFirstName(){
    return fName;
}

public String getSecondName(){
    return sName;
}

public String getStudentNumber(){
    return stuNumber;
}

// Save to Database
private void saveStudent(){
    // DBConnect db = new DBConnect();

}
}
```

The exception caused by non empty constructor

[image: The exception caused by non empty constructor]

The print test showing null values in Student fields

[image: The print test showing null values in Student fields]

Please let me know how I can make things any clearer,

Thanks.

Comment: Your setters should probably match the names of the fields. I don't think it is looking for the private fields. It's probably looking for the setters and not finding any.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you were right! At first I thought you weren't but it was a typo on my end. If you answer the question I will give you a tick. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names in the column mapping array should respond to the names of the setters rather than the fields themselves. If it can't find a setter that correspond to the name, it can't set the value.